# CiviReport: Field not found when sorting by Case Type as a section header

Tags: civireport

I've replicated this on a second Drupal/Civi 4.7.27 site so I don't believe it's limited to me, but could do with a bit of assistance before putting it on JIRA.

Attempting to create a Case Detail report with the following fields:

> [x] Subject
>
> [x] Client name
>
> Case type
>
> Case status

Sorting:

> Case Type > Ascending > Section Header/Group by
>
> Status > Ascending
>
> Start Date > Ascending

And I then get the following error message. This is **only** replicated with the Section Header/Group By enabled on Case Type.

Could anyone assist? Errors below:

```
 Dec 11 14:17:00  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
[callback] => Array
    (
        [0] => CRM_Core_Error
        [1] => handle
    )

[code] => -19
[message] => DB Error: no such field
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS case_civireport.id as civicrm_case_id, case_civireport.subject as civicrm_case_subject, case_civireport.start_date as civicrm_case_start_date, case_civireport.status_id as civicrm_case_status_id, case_civireport.case_type_id as civicrm_case_case_type_id, contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_client_sort_name, contact_civireport.id as civicrm_contact_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(relationship_civireport.relationship_type_id) ORDER BY relationship_civireport.relationship_type_id) as civicrm_relationship_case_role, civireport_case_types.title as case_type_name , case_civireport.case_type_name as civicrm_case_case_type_name 
         FROM civicrm_case case_civireport
LEFT JOIN civicrm_case_contact civireport_case_contact on civireport_case_contact.case_id = case_civireport.id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact contact_civireport ON contact_civireport.id = civireport_case_contact.contact_id

         LEFT JOIN  civicrm_relationship relationship_civireport ON relationship_civireport.case_id = case_civireport.id

         LEFT JOIN civicrm_address address_civireport
                ON contact_civireport.id = address_civireport.contact_id AND
                   address_civireport.is_primary = 1 
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_case_type civireport_case_types
      ON case_civireport.case_type_id = civireport_case_types.id
   WHERE ( case_civireport.is_deleted = 0 )  GROUP BY case_civireport.id  ORDER BY civireport_case_types.title ASC  LIMIT 0, 50 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'case_civireport.case_type_name' in 'field list']
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS case_civireport.id as civicrm_case_id, case_civireport.subject as civicrm_case_subject, case_civireport.start_date as civicrm_case_start_date, case_civireport.status_id as civicrm_case_status_id, case_civireport.case_type_id as civicrm_case_case_type_id, contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_client_sort_name, contact_civireport.id as civicrm_contact_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(relationship_civireport.relationship_type_id) ORDER BY relationship_civireport.relationship_type_id) as civicrm_relationship_case_role, civireport_case_types.title as case_type_name , case_civireport.case_type_name as civicrm_case_case_type_name 
         FROM civicrm_case case_civireport
LEFT JOIN civicrm_case_contact civireport_case_contact on civireport_case_contact.case_id = case_civireport.id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact contact_civireport ON contact_civireport.id = civireport_case_contact.contact_id

         LEFT JOIN  civicrm_relationship relationship_civireport ON relationship_civireport.case_id = case_civireport.id

         LEFT JOIN civicrm_address address_civireport
                ON contact_civireport.id = address_civireport.contact_id AND
                   address_civireport.is_primary = 1 
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_case_type civireport_case_types
      ON case_civireport.case_type_id = civireport_case_types.id
   WHERE ( case_civireport.is_deleted = 0 )  GROUP BY case_civireport.id  ORDER BY civireport_case_types.title ASC  LIMIT 0, 50 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'case_civireport.case_type_name' in 'field list']
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS case_civireport.id as civicrm_case_id, case_civireport.subject as civicrm_case_subject, case_civireport.start_date as civicrm_case_start_date, case_civireport.status_id as civicrm_case_status_id, case_civireport.case_type_id as civicrm_case_case_type_id, contact_civireport.sort_name as civicrm_contact_client_sort_name, contact_civireport.id as civicrm_contact_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(relationship_civireport.relationship_type_id) ORDER BY relationship_civireport.relationship_type_id) as civicrm_relationship_case_role, civireport_case_types.title as case_type_name , case_civireport.case_type_name as civicrm_case_case_type_name 
         FROM civicrm_case case_civireport
LEFT JOIN civicrm_case_contact civireport_case_contact on civireport_case_contact.case_id = case_civireport.id
LEFT JOIN civicrm_contact contact_civireport ON contact_civireport.id = civireport_case_contact.contact_id

         LEFT JOIN  civicrm_relationship relationship_civireport ON relationship_civireport.case_id = case_civireport.id

         LEFT JOIN civicrm_address address_civireport
                ON contact_civireport.id = address_civireport.contact_id AND
                   address_civireport.is_primary = 1 
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_case_type civireport_case_types
      ON case_civireport.case_type_id = civireport_case_types.id
   WHERE ( case_civireport.is_deleted = 0 )  GROUP BY case_civireport.id  ORDER BY civireport_case_types.title ASC  LIMIT 0, 50 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'case_civireport.case_type_name' in 'field list']"]
)
```

Comment: Would it be worth replicating on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org? Usually a good step before JIRA. Though seems to be non-functioning currently

Comment: Have replicated it on Circle Interactive's demo site (https://demo.circle-interactive.co.uk) at least, so it's definitely a whole-CiviCRM issue. Awaiting my account approval to post it on JIRA now. My first bug - how exciting!

Comment: Cool. Add the JIRA link as an Answer when you get it, then you can update that answer when it gets a fix.